# How to install Native Instruments in Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have deleted my Instruments accidently from my Mac at location 
MacintoshHD->Developer->Applications->Instruments

How can I bring it back?? Now I am not able to find it in spotlight. It is in xcode but it is not native. I have to use the native one. I have tried but not able to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Redownload the command line tools -> https://developer.apple.com/xcode/. Click Looking for additional developer tools?

Another option is redownload Xcode

Comment: What is this "Native Instruments" you are talking about? I only understand that you need to get XCode to get Instruments. Mac OS does not come with Instruments pre-installed, and Instruments doesn't appear to be a separate download (which is crazy since XCode is some 2-4 GB in size, and that's overkill for a non-developer wanting to get a small utility). Am I looking at this wrong?